why is my fragment not using the full screen?
i just started learning to code in java and started using android studio for the app development, and when i use the fragment it's just on the top of the screen. i'm realy lost and i don't know what to do now
  <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        android:background="@color/material_dynamic_primary80"
        android:clipToOutline="false"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:padding="16dp">


this is my fragment code
i tried to increse the dp of the constraint layout but i know it's just a tamporary and useles solusion especially because it doesn't compleatly goes on the whole screen and because on the larger dp's the stuff inside just gets inaccessible from distortion

Can you share how it looks like? Also, can you share the code the resides in the host activity?

So as fragment is loaded within an activity, you might have used a FrameLayout or FragmentContainerView there and its height may not be match_parent.
Hence just set height and width of that container where you are inflating your fragment.
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

Note: Do this in your Activity where you have used the container layout to load the fragment.
